# Generate GridView with flutter using index

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

what I am trying to do is generate a GridView with flutter with the index which is defined above, but it said "Undefined name index" for some reason, can you help me with that please.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(items: List<String>.generate(1000, (index) => "Item $index")));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(

          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar:
            AppBar(title:
            Text('List View Vertical'),),
            body:
              GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: List.generate(100, index)(
                    return Center(child: Text('Items $index',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),);
                  ))
        )

    );
  }
}
```

The result I expect is generating 1000 rows of gridview using the index I have already defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `build()` with this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List View Vertical'),
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: items.map((title) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            '$title',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use the values from the property `items` that your are passing.

Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('List View Vertical'),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: items.map((text) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```